# How to calculate transmission?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, resource-recommendations, fiber-optics

How to calculate transmission of photonic fibers?

I dont see chapter about photonic fibers in the Agrawal book.

Comment: The intent of this question is fine in my opinion, but you'll need to provide more details as to what constitutes "good" for you. What's good for one person may not be good for another. Be as specific as you can.

Answer (score 1):

How about the book "[Nonlinear Fiber Optics](http://books.google.de/books/about/Nonlinear_Fiber_Optics.html?id=wjHP0oAVcScC)" from Govind Agraval? It starts on page 5 with a section "Fiber Losses" and there is a whole chapter about "Pulse propagation in fibers". Might be that you'll have to use numerical methods if facing a complicated model, though.